# Wpa ptk and gtk in detail

Tags: encryption, wifi, wireless, wpa2, wpa2-psk

I have been checking Pairwise and Group Transient keys in a network for security. I understand

PTK is derived from = PMK, AP nonce (ANonce), STA nonce (SNonce), AP MAC address, and STA MAC address

This means that every client will have a different PTK since nonce will be different for each handshake. GTK same for every client.

If so, how can i see other computers requests from wireshark in the network that are ***not*** intended for broadcast? How can my pc decrypt those packets if ptk is used to encrypt them ?

I heard that PSK might be enough to decrypt any packet since it is derived from SSID + password with a hashing algorithm.. and since every client has the same psk, that works but if so ptk is used for what ?

Note : PMK = PSK